# Reference compiled React javascript from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, isomorphic-javascript, isomorphic

I have a React app that renders markup based on user input and I need to be able to render the markup the same way without a client. I've seen other people accomplish this by using Nodejs, is it possible to access React Components from Node given a reference to a compiled and minified Javascript file (this file is my React code bundled).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is certainly possible with something like `reactDOMServer`. You can read more at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to do it on a server? Or just on a command line? Are you using any bundlers like Webpack or Parcel?

Comment: Hi Erwin, 


So glad you answered my, very obscure, question! 


Basically I have a React component in my app that users interact with that outputs HTML markup for them. I am looking to add this functionality to the server to generate this HTML, think of this feature as sort of like a smart suggestion. 


We are using Webpack to bundle our React source however I am not too familiar with Webpack. Thanks again with your help on this!

Comment: Ok.. I have added a suggestion to start reading up on Server-Side Rendering. Start at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html